# V8. How to get current platform pointer?

Tags: c++, v8

Is there way to get `v8::Platform` pointer if I have `v8::Isolate` and `v8::Context` pointers?

Or just like I can get `v8::Isolate` pointer by calling static method `v8::Isolate::GetCurrent()`?

Answer (score 0):

There is `v8::debug::GetCurrentPlatform()`; it doesn't even need an Isolate or Context pointer.

That said, it might be easier to just keep around a pointer to the `Platform` instance you initially passed to V8 when you initialized it.

Comment: I have seen this method in V8 source inside `internal` namespace. In my code I have the error: `namespace v8::debug has no member GetCurrentPlatform`.

Comment: In my case I Initialize `v8::Platform` in parent dll and work with isolate and contexts in child(this dll can be reloaded multiple times per runtime session, so I can't initialize `v8::Platform` there). And there is no simple way to pass `v8::Platform` pointer to child dll.

Comment: Oh, right, I had missed that even the v8::debug:: version is defined in an internal header file. Looks like there is no publicly exposed way to get the current `Platform` then. Why do you need it? AFAICS `InitializePlatform` is the only method that needs a `Platform*`, and you only need to call that one once.

Comment: I need it for V8 Inspector implementation. There is method `v8::platform::PumpMessageLoop(v8::Platform*, v8::Isolate*)` that I should to call in loop when script paused on breakpoint